# Any way to Programmatically enable guided access using ionic capacitor/cordova cross platform?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cross-platform, capacitor

I am using **capacitor**, **ionic** and **react** and was wondering how this would be done? Are there any plugins that I can use? Is there native Ionic functionality anywhere?

Answer (score 0):

I believe [Capacitor is backwards compatible with Cordova](https://ionic.io/resources/articles/capacitor-vs-cordova-modern-hybrid-app-development) so you could use a Cordova plugin. I haven't tested the plugin but this one seems to do it for iOS: https://github.com/wizpanda/cordova-ios-guided-access
You have to be enrolled in some program though, as it states.

If you need other platforms, then you could expose those native capabilities/APIs with the core platform language (Koltin/Java for Android, C#/C++ for Windows, etc..) and fork/extend this plugin. That way, at least the iOS version is already done (given this works).